# Showing that $K^n\to (K^n)^* , v\mapsto -\bullet v$ is ismorphic

Tags: linear-algebra

> for $v\in K^n$, the dot product defines a linear transformation
> $-\bullet v: K^n\to K, w\mapsto w\bullet v$. Let $e_i$ be the i-the
> basis vector of $K^n$.
>
> Show that the function in the dual space $K^n\to (K^n)^* , v\mapsto
> -\bullet v$ is isomorphic.

I have to show that the function is linear and bijective. The linearity is given by the linearity of the dot product. How can I show the bijectivity?

Comment: The word "isomorphic" is not used to describe a function that is an isomorphism. Rather, "isomorphic" is an adjective that applies to the two spaces that have an isomorphism between them

Comment: thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a counterpart to Richard Jensen's answer, you can also prove injectivity (which implies surjectivity by the rank-nullity theorem). We just need to show that the map $v\mapsto - \bullet v$ has nullity $0$; i.e., that it maps any non-zero vector to a non-zero element of $(K^n)^*$.

Indeed, if $v$ is non-zero, then we have $v \bullet v \ne 0$, so $- \bullet v$ is not the zero map.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are in a finite dimensional vector space, surjectivity implies injectivity. So let us just prove surjectivity.

Let $f \in (K^n)^*$, and let $e_1, ... , e_n$ be the standard basis for $K^n$. Denote

$v_i = f(e_i)$

Now let $v=(v_1,v_2,...v_n)$. We have

$e_i \bullet v = v_i = f(e_i) $

so the linear functionals $f$ and $- \bullet v$ agree on a basis of $K^n$, and are therefore identical.